# Error running Ansible playbook with async on Windows host: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grp'

Tags: python, windows, powershell, ansible, runtime-error

I'm encountering an error while running an Ansible playbook with the async option on a Windows host. The specific error message I received is:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grp'
fatal: XXXX: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File \"C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1688652868.3399918-570410-89380102041944\\async_wrapper.ps1\", line 102, in <module>\r
    _ansiballz_main()\r
  File \"C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1688652868.3399918-570410-89380102041944\\async_wrapper.ps1\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\r
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\r
  File \"C:\\Users\\***\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible-tmp-1688652868.3399918-570410-89380102041944\\async_wrapper.ps1\", line 37, in invoke_module\r
    from ansible.module_utils import basic\r
  File \"C:\\Users\\SYS_AN~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ansible_ansible.legacy.async_wrapper_payload_5kjomgx5\\ansible_ansible.legacy.async_wrapper_payload.zip\\ansible\\module_utils\\basic.py\", line 39, in <module>\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grp'\r
", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1
```

However, my playbook includes a task that doesn't explicitly require the grp module:

```yaml
- name: Execute LONG RUNNING THING IN ASYNC'
  win_shell: |
    **LONG RUNNING SCRIPT**
  register: result
  async: 36000
  poll: 60
```

Could you please provide guidance on resolving the grp module error in the context of this task? Is there an alternative approach I can take to achieve my desired outcome without relying on the grp module? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried going around this by creating jobs and processes in powershell but that solution was unsuccessful, because after the play to create the process finished the process ended with it.

```yaml
- name: Execute
    win_shell: |
      try {
        $process = Start-Process -FilePath "powershell" -ArgumentList "Start-Sleep -Seconds 30" -Wait -PassThru 
        
        $process | Export-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
      }
      catch {
        exit 1
      }
    register: result
```

and then check the result with:

```yaml
- name: Check Result 
      win_shell: |
        $process = Import-Clixml -Path (Join-Path $ENV:temp 'processhandle.xml')
        $process2 = Get-Process -Id $process.Id
        Write-Host $process2.HasExited
        Write-Host $process2.Id
        
      register: finished
```

Comment: The requirement comes from [a common base file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py#L54) which use is triggered by the [async wrapper for Windows](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/powershell/async_wrapper.ps1). I did not dig further to see if this is the case only when using `win_shell` or not (and my PowerShell skills are inexistant anyway). But the easiest solution is to use the [`pip` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pip_module.html) to install `grp` on your target.

Comment: @Zeitounator I don't think its the problem with `win_shell`, because the play runs perfectly fine when I run it synchronously. I cant install `grp` beacuse it's a linux only module and is installed with python. Host has installed python version 3.11.4 and the pc im working from has 3.8.10. and Ansible 2.10.3. I tried to upgrade but it did nothing.

Comment: Read "only using win_shell **with the async feature**". Meanwhile I did not pay attention to what the `grp` module was. Now I did it seems pretty strange ansible tries to use it on windows. So either async does not work on windows (I don't believe it is the case) or there is something broken somewhere in your environment/configuration. I'll stop here for my part because I don't even have a windows host to test that.